# How to add prefix to the files while unzipping in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Trying to add prefix to all the files in directory while unzipping in Python. Is there a way to add prefix to the file while unzipping?

```
Code:
====
import pathlib
import shutil
import os

file_path = "/emp/status/"
shutil.rmtree(file_path, ignore_errors=True)
pathlib.Path(file_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
os.system("gzip -d " + file_path + "/*")


Output:
=======
data_0_1_0.csv
data_0_2_0.csv
data_0_3_0.csv


Required output:
================
emp_status_data_0_1_0.csv
emp_status_data_0_2_0.csv
emp_status_data_0_3_0.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
for filename in pathlib.Path(path).glob('*.csv')
    dst = f"emp_status_{filename}"
    os.rename(filename,  os.path.join(file_path, dst))
```