# Python add prefix to file names inside a directory

Tags: python, file-rename

I need to add a prefix to file names within a directory. Whenever I try to do it though, it tries to add the prefix to the beginning of the file path. That won't work. I have a few hundred files that I need to change, and I've been stuck on this for a while. Have any ideas? Here's the closest I've come to getting it to work. I found this idea in this thread: [How to add prefix to the files while unzipping in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130804/how-to-add-prefix-to-the-files-while-unzipping-in-python) If I could make this work inside my for loop to download and extract the files that would be cool, but it's okay if this happens outside of that loop.

```
import os
import glob
import pathlib

for file in pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Wells').glob("*WaterWells.*"):
    dst = f"County_{file}"
    os.rename(file, os.path.join(file, dst))
```

That produces this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Wells\\Alcona_WaterWells.cpg' -> 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Wells\\Alcona_WaterWells.cpg\\County_C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Wells\\Alcona_WaterWells.cpg'
```

I'd like to add "County_" to each file. The targeted files use this syntax: CountyName_WaterWells.ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.path.basename gets the file name, os.path.dirname gets directory names. Note that these may break if your slashes are in a weird direction. Putting them in your code, it would work like this

```
import os
import glob
import pathlib

for file in pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Wells').glob("*WaterWells.*"):
    dst = f"County_{os.path.basename(file)}"
    os.rename(file, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), dst))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I needed. I haven't explored the os library a lot, but it looks like I'll have to check things out more. I'm working with a lot of different datasets and it seems like the stuff in os will really come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your renaming variable, `dst`, adds 'County_' before the entire path, which is given by the `file` variable.

If you take `file` and break it up with something like `file.split("/")` (where you should replace the slash with whatever appears between directories when you print `file` to terminal) then you should be able to get `file` broken up as a list, where the final element will be the current filename. Modify just this in the loop, put the whole thing pack together using `"".join(_path + modified_dst)` and then pass *this* to `os.rename`.